# web.py doesn't find file

Tags: python, html, web.py

I try to create a little website using web.py and webpysocketio, and I have a problem: Web.py doesn't seem to find any file besides the index.html.

Here's my webpy app:

```
import web
from socketio import SocketIOServer
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
from webpy_socketio import *

urls = (
    '/', 'index',
)

urls += socketio_urls

app = web.application(urls, globals())

SOCKETIO_HOST = ""
SOCKETIO_PORT = 8080

application = app.wsgifunc()



if __name__ == "__main__":
       SocketIOServer((SOCKETIO_HOST, SOCKETIO_PORT), application, resource="socket.io").serve_forever()

class index:
    def GET(self):
        render = web.template.render('templates/')
        return render.index()

@on_message(channel="my channel")
def message(request, socket, context, message):
    socket.send_and_broadcast_channel(message)
```

In my template folder I have the `index.html` (`and the socketio_scripts.html`):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>webpysocketio TEST</title>
    <object type="text/html" data="socketio_scripts.html">
        <script>
            var socket = new io.Socket();
            socket.connect();
            socket.on('connect', function() {
                socket.subscribe('my channel');
                socket.send('asdf');
            });
        </script>
   </object>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now when I run the webiste, after I visit it in a browser, I get the following on my terminal:

```
IP - - [DATE] "GET /socketio_scripts.html HTTP/1.1" 404 135 0.004273
```

Why does it not find the other html file?

Comment: Do the other files have the correct permissions?

Comment: yes, I tried with different permissions and in different folders (templates/, static/ etc.) but it always gives me a 404

Comment: I put some suggestions in an Answer - it's too difficult to format code readably in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `/socketio_scripts.html` is not the correct `url` for that file - it seems odd that that file would be at the root of your document tree.

According to several pages, it should be in `.../templates/`. I also doubt very much it would ever be accessed by `GET`

Have a look at [the web.py tutorial](http://webpy.org/tutorial3). One big difference with your code is that all the pages have to be listed in the `urls` dispatch table:

```
urls = (
  '/', 'hello',
  '/bye', 'bye')
```

Answer (score -1):

The static files which you dont want to be served from GET function have to be placed in a static file , in your example the "socketio_scripts.html"
and accessed by the full url "http://localhost/static/socketio_scripts.html". http://webpy.org/cookbook/staticfiles